# Using scalajs Diode and an ApplicationCircuit with a handler defined for a Posts (sequence), can I somehow map it to a ModelProxy[Post] individual?

Tags: reactjs, flux, scala.js

#### Edit 2:

There *has to be a better way than what I am doing in my haribranedness*

```
        <.div(
          ApplicationCircuit.zoom(_.posts.postList).value.map {
            case p: Post ⇒
              ApplicationCircuit.connect(_.posts.postList.filterNot(x ⇒ x == p).head)(x ⇒ PostItemC(PostItemC.Props(x)))
          }
        )
```

It's a weird question but I have my reasons. When I render each `Post` from `ModelProxy[Posts]` where `case class Posts(seq: Seq[Post])`, I'd like to instead render a `ModelProxy[Post]`, a proxy for each one. This will allow me to, moving forward, wrap it in a `Pot` and then handle individual `Post` updates, deletes, etc with great ease.

I'm having trouble finagling the object into that form, though, but I feel like there are so many `zoomFlatMap` and `zoomFlatMapRW` etc  that something should help me get from where I am to there. That said, I am lost.

### Edit

My closest attempt

```
    <.div(
      ApplicationCircuit.zoom(_.posts.postList).value.map {
        case p: Post ⇒
          ApplicationCircuit.connect(_.posts.postList.filterNot(x ⇒ x == p).head)(_.)
      }
```

ie, `ApplicationCircuit.connect(_.posts.postList)(proxy ⇒ ModelProxy(????))`

```
object ApplicationCircuit
  extends Circuit[ApplicationModel]
  with ReactConnector[ApplicationModel] {

  addProcessor(new DiodeLogger[ApplicationModel]())

  override protected def initialModel: ApplicationModel = ApplicationModel(
    Posts(Seq()),
    Masthead(NavigationItems(Seq()), "JustinTampa", "JustinTampa.com", active = false)
  )

  override protected def actionHandler = composeHandlers(
    new PostHandler(zoomRW(_.posts)((m,v) ⇒ m.copy(posts = v))),
    new MastheadHandler(zoomRW(_.masthead)((m,v) ⇒ m.copy(masthead = v)))
  )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your render code you should really only use functions from the `ReactConnector` trait, like `wrap` and `connect`. For this case it's probably best to `connect` to `Posts` and then render individual items in the sequence.

```
ApplicationCircuit.connect(_.posts.postList){ model =>
  <.div(model().map(post => PostItemC(PostItemC.Props(post))))
}
```

Then in your `PostItemC` component you should implement the `shouldComponentUpdate` method, so that posts that have not changed are not rendered again when the `postList` changes. Something like,

```
shouldComponentUpdate(scope => scope.currentProps.post ne scope.nextProps.post)
```

Finally make sure your component defines the `key` property so that React will know how to connect the post components when they are updated. Otherwise you will get a runtime warning about not having `key` in an array of components.

This way when the model changes (generating a new `postList`) React will render the list again, but will skip rendering items that have not changed.

In contrast if you only `connect` individual posts, then changes to the list itself (like adding or removing posts) do not trigger rendering.